# How to continue a process after returning a response in a tide endpoint

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Is it possible to send a response from an endpoint and then continue running ?(in the background) So when the endpoint gets called the caller gets some response but the server continues doing things :

```
    app.at("/endpoint").post(myendpoint);

    async fn myendpoint(mut req: Request<State>) -> tide::Result {
    let body= Body::from_json(some_json).unwrap();
    Ok(body.into()) //continue doing stuff after this (calling another function) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spawn a thread. Even after you process your request and return the response, the thread will continue doing what it needs to do for as long as needed.

An example:

```
use std::thread;

let hnd = thread::spawn(|| {
    // Put your thread code here
});
```

That's a regular thread, no *async* stuff. Generally, if you expect hundreds or thousands of concurrent calls, you might consider another, more-scalable approach.

Read more on thread spawning [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html).

Comment: You can do the same remaining in async by spawning a *task* in whatever executor you're using e.g. [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html), or even [`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html). Though if that's a common need (rather than a one-off) you might want a task or two serving as queue processors rather than spawn ad-hoc tasks.

Comment: I'm likely misunderstanding threads. Isn't it that if the main thread finishes, then its spawned thread also terminates even if processing isn't done?

I'm also implementing something on a middleware, client-server architecture.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused.

I saw this on [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-01-threads.html), 
*“Note that when the main thread of a Rust program completes, all spawned threads are shut down, whether or not they have finished running.”*